# Groovy exception. While fetching news from seattletimes.com

Tags: groovy

```
    **Exception thrown**
```

> java.net.UnknownHostException: www.seattletimes.comseattle-news.rss   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(UnknownSource)
>     at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(UnknownSource)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at News.getNews(SeattleNewsMash.groovy:14)  at
>   News$getNews.call(Unknown Source)     at
>   SeattleNewsMash.run(SeattleNewsMash.groovy:105)

**CODE**

```
@Grab ('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1')
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.Method
import groovyx.net.http.HttpURLClient
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser



class News {

  String base = 'http://www.seattletimes.com'
  def getNews(int count) {
  def items = new XmlParser().parse(base + 'seattle_news.rss').channel[0].item[0..count]
        return items
    }
}


    // body of script
        def news = new News()
        def SeattleStories = news.getNews(3)
        println "Seattle News (unformatted):"
        println SeattleStories
        println "-----------------------------"
```

Comment: Try adding a slash between the domain (`base`) and the file path `seattle_news.rss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to contact the host "www.seattletimes.comseattle-news.rss", which doesn't exist.  You probably need to add a slash (at least) between "www.seattletimes.com" and "seattle-news.rss" when you create your `XmlParser`.

Comment: It helped. It is "/feed" instead of "/seattle-news.rss" .
Thank you:)